# do all players win star realms pirates co-op

Tags: cooperation, star-realms

OK, with the Star Realms Pirates of the Dark Star co-op challenge, if a player dies but at least one other remaining team member still beats the Pirates, is it a team win or an individual win? e.g. if Bob and Sally play, and Bob is eliminated, but Sally still hangs on and wins it, is it a team victory, or was it just Sally who won?

Answer (score 1):

By the nature of it being a co-op then everybody wins.  I can't anything specific in those rules to say an eliminated player doesn't win so I wouldn't rule that just those surviving are winners.  It seems very against the spirit of a co-op game to try and claim you won solo unless thats specifically in the rules such as Archipelago where everyone wins/loses and if players win there is a 'grand winner' amongst them.